# Axios GET svg request

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, axios

I am trying to get Axios to treat a get request for SVGs as text and not JSON. There is an error produced in chrome

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "z".
```

I looked up Axios transformRequest config property but I'm not sure if this is the way to go about having axios treat the SVG as text. I also haven't found many resources online relating to this specific issue.

The function is as follows:

```
    export async function getSVG(url: string): Promise<string> {
    const config = {responseType: 'text'};
    const response = await axios.get(url, config);

    const svgData = response.data;

    return svgData;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your current JavaScript to your question? The part that is producing given error. It would highly support us giving you the correct advice.

Comment: "I am trying to get Axios to treat a get request for SVGs as text and not JSON." — There is no way that the error message you got would be because anything is trying to parse it as JSON. That looks like it is trying to parse it as SVG and the SVG has errors in it.

Comment: @Quentin can you point to where I can learn on how to debug this error?

Comment: It's for sure an SVG error, and not a javascript one :) Show us the svg! ;)

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
icon_svg = await axios({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'text/plain',
}).then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
  return response.data;
});
```